# Google Play Android Developer: Who is responsible to pay for taxes (non-us residents)

Tags: android, google-play

I live in South Korea and I have an app on Google Play store. Recently, my app is making some money through in-app purchases and I have received my first payment. I have noticed that 30% of my payment was deducted by Google as "transaction fee". My question is: Do I need to pay income tax in South Korea individually, or Google is already taking care of the tax payments? I'm an individual. I don't know if Google, as a company, is responsible to pay for my income tax, or I myself as an individual should pay taxes individually.

30% of the money is already taken by Google, if I'm supposed to pay the tax for the remaining money, almost nothing will be left for myself :(

Comment: voted to close as this is not a programming problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related, but legal/taxes one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not a Google employee (you don't have an employment contract with them), so Google is not responsible for paying your taxes, but you are. You should pay taxes for the income you get, so the remaining 70% of your sales.

Answer (score 1):

The 30% does not include taxes. You are responsible for paying these.